# how to create an Expandable Column using ui5-table

Tags: sapui5

How can I create an Expandable/Collapsable Columns like accordion using ui5-table? I couldn't find it within sap.ui.table.Table samples or don't even know if other tables supports this.

Comment: Can you may show us an example/link/screenshot of what you mean with expandable columns?

Comment: @JulianSchmuckli it should be similar to this example, https://github.com/SAP/ui5-webcomponents/issues/455 but instead of clicking a row, user will click column header icon that will horizontal expand/collaps

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

- Attach to the "columnPress" event of the column to detect a Click on the table column.
- In the Event detect, if the expandable column is clicked and toggle a property in the ViewModel
- switch the visibility in the the Column Template

> ```
> <Column>
>  <m:Label text="Expand" />
>   <template>
>       <m:HBox>
>       <m:Text text="unexpanded" visible="{= !${viewModel>/IsExpanded}}"/>
>       <m:HBox visible="{= !!${viewModel>/IsExpanded}}">   
>          <m:Text text="expanded1"/>
>          <m:Text text="expanded2"/>
>          <m:Text text="expanded3"/>
>         </m:HBox>
>       </m:HBox>
>   </template>
> </Column>
> ```